# Mysql query to convert a record in one table to number of records in other table based on number fo field values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a query in mysql that can convert a record in one table into various records in another table based on field value from first table

I have a table Table1 with fields such as

```
ID Name Address1 Address2 Address3 Address4

1  A    abc      qwe      wer      rty
2  T    xcv  dfgg     kkkl     
3  V    fgh
4  G    tyn  mfg      uio
.
.
```

another table Table2 with fileds as

```
ID AddressNumber Address
1   1            abc
1   2            qwe
1   3            wer
1   4            rty
2   1            xcv
2   2            dfgg
2   3            kkk1
3   1            fgh
.
.
```

simply its one to many relationship between the tables ie. for one ID there can be multiple address(at max 4 at least 1).

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Please clarify. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: A single query would be quite unlikely to do what you want.

Comment: i need to write an stored procedure for the same so can it be achieved without using cursor?

Comment: I have data in Table1 and based on Id and values in address fields i want to insert the records in another table table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:** If you want to UNPIVOT your first table and insert the result into another table, you can do it this way

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, AddressNumber, Address)
SELECT id, 
       AddressNumber,
       CASE AddressNumber 
          WHEN 1 THEN Address1
          WHEN 2 THEN Address2
          WHEN 3 THEN Address3
          WHEN 4 THEN Address4
       END Address
  FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 1 AddressNumber UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 
) i
HAVING Address IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY id, AddressNumber;
```

The result in `table2`:

```
| ID | ADDRESSNUMBER | ADDRESS |
|----|---------------|---------|
|  1 |             1 |     abc |
|  1 |             2 |     qwe |
|  1 |             3 |     wer |
|  1 |             4 |     rty |
|  2 |             1 |     xcv |
|  2 |             2 |    dfgg |
|  2 |             3 |    kkkl |
|  3 |             1 |     fgh |
|  4 |             1 |     tyn |
|  4 |             2 |     mfg |
|  4 |             3 |     uio |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699bd/1)** demo

Comment: actually the id field that i have taken here is just an example i have another 10 digit integer field as primary and that is random

Comment: `id` doesn't matter in this query. numbers 1 to 4 represents numbers of `AddressN` columns in `table1`. They just happened to be the same as ordinal numbers of address columns. So use whatever id you have.

Comment: what i an trying here is to insert records into second table based on the primary key and address field values. I get data in first table but need to break it down based on primary key

Comment: Well, all you need is just to add `INSERT INTO table2 ...`. See updated answer and sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: what happens when i have field names like FirstAddrtypeWho,FirstAddress1,FirstAddress2,FirstAddressCity,FirstAddressEffectiveDate,SecondAddrtypeWho,SecondAddress1,SecondAddressCity,SecondAddressEffectiveDate and likewise for third and fourth.... here the scenerio is that instead of numbers i have word format... I also have fields like SpecCode1,Spec1Description,Spec1BoardCertified,Spec1BoardEFF,Spec1BoardEND,SpecCode2,Spec2Description,Spec2BoardCertified,Spec1BoardEFF,Spec1BoardEND and so on upto SpecCode6... how do i handle these..Please help or suggest. Thanks!

Comment: @PeeyushPandey It's not encouraged here on SO to change the scope of the question. Therefore please consider to post another question providing extended table schema, sample data and desired output (the usual drill) and other SO members or I will be happy to help you (if you want to you can post a link to a new question here in comments)

Comment: is the opposite possible? please check my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273052/convert-multiple-records-to-multiple-columns