# convert multiple records to multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I want a mysql query that can convert records into multiple fields.

i have added an example here,

Given a table A, which look like

Table A

|  id|order|data|item|Price|

-----+-----+----------------

|   1|    1|   P| 1  | 50  |

|   2|    1|   P| 2  | 60  |

|   3|    1|   P| 3  | 70  |

|   4|    2|   Q| 1  | 50  |

Table B

|  langId| id  |langCode|

---------+-----+----------------

|   1    |    1|   02   |

|   2    |    1|   04   |

|   3    |    1|   05   |

|   4    |    2|   01   |

|   1    |    2|   02   |

|   2    |    3|   04   |

|   3    |    4|   05   |

|   4    |    4|   01   |

based on the above two table,I like to write a query that would insert the data into the third table, that looks like the following::

id | langCode1 |langCode2 |langCode3 |langCode4 |langCode5 |langCode6 |

1  | 02        |04        |05        |          |          |          |

2  | 01        |02        |          |          |          |          |

3  | 04        |          |          |          |          |          |

4  | 05        |01        |          |          |          |          |

I have tried to create two different queries and then a join to achieve this, but that did not gave the desired output, can anyone help me to get out of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is langCode6 the largest or should this be dynamic?? and i dont see the relation between table A and table B and your desired output can you explain this better?

Comment: The id field relates Table A and Table B, and in the output table i want to join the two tables and relate all the langcode related to particular id in one row. eg: its like in first table(Table A) I have information related to a person while in second table i have information related to the language he speaks, and in my final output i want all the languags he speks in one row related to that person) LangCode10 is the largest in output table

Comment: Can you place you complete example data here http://sqlfiddle.com? because it is not clear..

Comment: Please have a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e473/1/0

Comment: so far i have succeeded in by making a use of group_concat(). the query goes like this :                                         select s.id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT langCode)
from Table1 r join Table2 s
  on r.id=s.id
GROUP BY s.id;                                                                now i want the comma separated values to be inserted into different fields in Table3 based on id .